# Batch variable setting and comparison, unexpected error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
if '%class%'=='Mage' set basehealth=100 & set basemana=200 & set health=100 & set mana=200 & set speed=30 & goto cm
if '%class%'=='Warrior' set basehealth=200 & set basemana=50 & set health=200 & set mana=50 & set speed=20 & goto cw
if '%class%'=='Paladin' set basehealth=150 & set basemana=150 & set health=150 & set mana=150 & set speed=25 & goto cp
```

It when I choose `mage` and get to this part it says '=='Mage' was unexpected at this time...

Here is where I set %class%...

I have no idea what the issue is because it was working earlier... Also I am fairly new to batch.

```
set /p descisionm=
if '%descisionm%'=='1' set class=Mage & goto mageline 
if '%descisionm%'=='2' goto classchoose
```

Comment: @Paul - Nice edit. I couldn't figure out how to read the last half of the original question. Luckily, I already understood the problem based on the error message and past experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is almost surely a result of the `class` value containing a trailing space. The IF command terminates the value expression at the first space, and then expects the next non-space text to be `==`, but finds `'` instead.

You could prevent the syntax error by enclosing both sides by double quotes instead of single quotes, which allows the value to contain spaces. But you still won't get the correct result because `"Mage "` does not equal `"Mage"`.

The best way to avoid trailing spaces when defining variables is to enclose the entire assignment within double quotes. Everything after the last quote is ignored.

```
set "class=Mage"  & rem the trailing spaces are not included in the value :-)
```

One other tip - you can efficiently string together many numeric assignments with a single SET /A command, and spaces are ignored when using SET /A:

```
set /a basehealth=100, basemana=200, health=100, mana=200, speed=30 & goto cm
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, and thank you very much for your extra tip!